# Iptables list is printed different to actual ruleset

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, shell

I encountered something strange, when I run `iptables --list-rules`:

```
-A INPUT -s 172.29.0.2/32 -j ACCEPT
```

But the table prints something different to this, `iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  40c5d8f8ed6f         anywhere
```

Maybe someone could tell me why this is the case? Is this normal?

Comment: Try "iptables -L -n" for numeric output. That value could be a string, not a number. Check your /etc/hosts file to see if that IP is mapped to that string. You could also try "nslookup <ip address>" to see if that string is returned as a hostname. Also, which iptables version are you using, and which distro are you using?